# Limit maximum concurrent HTTP connections per IP by dropping old connections

Tags: apache, http, webserver, iptables

I want to limit maximum concurrent HTTP connections per IP by dropping old connections, instead of blocking new ones.

To better explain what I want, let me give an example:

I have a website serving MP3 files. Somebody is entering my website and try to download lets say 20 files concurrently. I want to limit this to 10 for example, and whenever he click a new link, I want to close the oldest active connection.

Any iptables or apache configuration solution is welcomed.

You can also recommend any resources to write a new apache module to achieve this. I am good at C/C++ coding in linux :) But I never deal with apache modules before.